# CSS translatey to move to the next DIV using anchors

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap template which include a navigation bar with 3 links. Each link point to an anchor.
Each anchor is a SECTION with height set to 100%. The scrollbar is hidden so the only way to navigate to the next section is by using the navigation bar.

I want to add an animation while the anchor is change.
I setup my template and the animation but I don't understand why my DIVS goes offset instead of scrolling as expected.

My JSFiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/raffaeu/qu4skwf4/

I set the transitions as following:

```
#home:target{
    -webkit-transform: translateY( 0px);
    transform: translateY( 0px );
}
#about:target{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
#contact:target{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-200%);
    transform: translateY(-200%);
}
```

And this is how I set the animation for each section

```
section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:0;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I belive that in this case CSS translate is unnecessary and even plain wrong approach. Scrollbar is invented for a reason, and you should not take it away from page visitors. Also, think about mobile users.

I suggest better using **jQuery.offset** function and add animation, like this:

```
function scrollToAnchor(aid){
   var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
}

scrollToAnchor('id3');
```

Comment: This solution works only if scrollbar is visible.
The website is fully responsive and we do not want to show the scrollbar, I knew this solution already but it is not what I am asking here